# Pthread "manager" thread crashed due to get signal 33

Tags: pthreads, embedded-linux

I have linux application on embedded linux that uses pthread library. From time to time pthread "manager" thread get signal 33 and crashed.

How do I know who is sending the signal?

Strace log:

```
...
18:15:07 getppid()                      = 30
18:15:07 poll([{fd=31, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = 0
18:15:09 getppid()                      = 30
18:15:09 poll([{fd=31, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = 0
18:15:11 getppid()                      = 30
18:15:11 poll([{fd=31, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = 0
18:15:13 getppid()                      = 30
18:15:13 poll([{fd=31, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
18:15:13 --- SIGRT_1 (Unknown signal 33) @ 0 (0) ---
18:15:13 getppid()                      = 30
18:15:13 wait4(-1, [WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGSEGV], WNOHANG|__WCLONE, NULL) = 68
18:15:13 --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal 33 is used internally by the pthreads library (it is referred to as `SIGSETXID`, and is raised by the library for every thread whenever one of the uids or gids of the process are changed).

It should not cause a thread to crash.  Why do you believe this signal is responsible?

Comment: Updated my post. Added strace log.

Comment: @Grey: That looks like one of your other threads is initially encountering the segfault, which then causes the entire process to terminate.  Try running the process under gdb or capturing a core file to load in gdb.

Comment: I will take your advice. Thanks!

Comment: There're some libraries like libbacktrace, will utilize this signal to unwind target process. So basically it's a implementation specific signal.